# what is the conditional probability $P(X+Y=2|X-Y=0)$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with identical distributions The variables takes values $0,1, 2$ with probabilities $\frac12,\frac14,\frac14$. what is the conditional  probability 
$P(X+Y=2|X-Y=0)$?

Comment: are you sure that you are looking for $P(x+y=\frac{2}{x}-y=0$ since  you wont be able to find $(x,y)$ such that $x+y=0$ and $\frac{2}{x}-y=0$ simultaneously. If it is the case, then the probability will almost surely be zero. But I let the far more intelligent people on this board sort it out..:)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: @Chinny84 It's probably $P(x+y=2| x-y=0)$.

Comment: @5xum argh..The overloading of the "\" operator! Cheers, that makes way more sense!

Answer (score 3):

Answer is 1/6

- ${(X+Y=2)}\cap{(X-Y=0)} = (X=1) \cap (Y=1)$
  reason is : $(X-Y=0)\Longleftrightarrow (X=Y)$...

so : $P((X+Y=2) \cap (X-Y=0))=P(X=1) \times P(Y=1)=(1/4)\times(1/4)=1/16$ (*X* and *Y*  being independant)

- $P(X-Y=0)=P(X=Y)=P(((X=0) \cap (Y=0)) \cup ((X=1) \cap(Y=1)) \cup((X=2) \cap(Y=2)) = P((X=0) \cap (Y=0))+P((X=1) \cap(Y=1))+P((X=2) \cap(Y=2))=(1/2)\times (1/2)+(1/4)\times (1/4)+(1/4)\times (1/4) = 3/8 $

Finally : $P(X+Y=2/X-Y=0)=\frac{P(X=1)\times P(Y=1)}{P(X=Y)}=\frac{(1/16)}{(3/8)}=1/6$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

By definition $$P(X+Y=2 | X-Y = 0)= \frac{P(X+Y=2,X=Y)}{P(X=Y)} = \frac{P(X=Y=1)}{P(X=Y)} = \frac{1}{16 \cdot P(X=Y)}.$$ Now try to find $P(X=Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The table of probabilities is (using a common denominator)

```
X   Y: 0     1     2
-     ----  ----  ---- 
0     4/16  2/16  2/16
1     2/16  1/16  1/16 
2     2/16  1/16  1/16
```

$X-Y=0$ is the top left to bottom right diagonal.  $X+Y=2$ is the top right to bottom left  diagonal.

So $P(X+Y=2|X−Y=0) = \dfrac{1/16}{4/16+1/16+1/16} = \dfrac16$.